# What happens to code after history.back()?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, concurrency

I have code like the following:

```
window.history.back();
myFunction(10);
```

- Is `history.back()` a blocking / non-blocking call?
- Is there an assurance that `myFunction()` will be executed? or will not be executed?
- Is this a possible race condition where `history.back()` happens asynchronously and 
  whether `myFunction()` is called depends on timing of uncontrollable events?

Comment: Interesting question, but what are your experiences on the matter?  Have you tried this yourself?

Comment: This is a good question! Reading [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110113/history.html#traverse-the-history-by-a-delta), `myFunction` could be called if the `BeforeUnloadEvent` cancels the navigation at the very least

Comment: @Peter The function runs; however i want to be sure.

Comment: @teddbytee, sure : good question, but your own experiences on the matter are always interesting as extra info

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110113/history.html#traverse-the-history-by-a-delta) says that `history.back` [queues a task](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110113/webappapis.html#queue-a-task).

The actual history manipulation code (which is internal to the JS implementation) will therefore be executed during the next run of the main [event loop](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110113/webappapis.html#event-loop). Your call to `myFunction` executes synchronously in the current round of execution, so it will always be executed in compliant environments.

However, only synchronous code in `myFunction` is guaranteed to execute. Consider this example:

```
function myFunction() {
  console.log('synchronous');
  debugger

  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('async');
    debugger
  })
}

window.history.back();
myFunction();
```

The first debugger statement is always hit. The second, which is deferred to a future event loop tick using `setTimeout`, will not.

[This article](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2013/10/27/the-javascript-event-loop-explained/) is a good explanation of the JavaScript event loop

Comment: I found an exception to this in chrome 40.0.0.0 on devices running android 6 API 23. Code after history.back() doesn't executes.