# Chrome debugger statement not hit after calling history.back()

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

As the title says, try pasting this into the Chrome devtools console on this page.  The code is shown in the sources tab, but the `debugger;` statement doesn't act as a breakpoint.  Breakpoints don't seem to work after the `history.back()` either.

```
window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title",  window.location.href.substring(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/")) + '?test');
history.back();
debugger;
```

Could someone tell me why this is?
Is there a way to alter this behaviour?

I'm running Chrome 49.0.2623.112 (Official Build) m (32-bit)

Comment: `history.back()` navigates away, like `location.reload` does. It immediately stops all scripts and never returns. There is no more code executed.

Comment: @Bergi, that's not true, or rather not accurate. Test it yourself with, say, an `alert()` instead of `debugger`

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer by doing the research for you :-):

Please check out references in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25543052/what-happens-to-code-after-history-back) for the details, but the high-level explanation is that the `history.back()` call is a non-blocking call. When it gets executed at a later iteration of the event loop, it most likely causes a reset of some sort, thus preventing the complete effect of `debugger;`

In my experiment, if you'd replace your `debugger;` call with a scheduled one: `setTimeout(function() { debugger; }, {{anything greater than 1ms}} );`
it works as expected.

Interesting observation, though!

Comment: Thanks for the information.  When I try the scheduled debugger, it only works if it's delayed past around 10ms - it's not consistent.  Also, as G. Stoynev points out, execution does continue as normal.  The SO answer you link to also suggests that the standard debugger call should always be called, as it's synchronous.  The delayed one might not be, but as in this case we aren't actually leaving the page, I assume it generally will.  It must be something strange happening in the developer tools.  It doesn't feel like it should behave this way.